# Python: convert dictionary into a cvs file

Tags: python, list, csv

This is my current code:

```py
import csv
data = {'name' : ['Dave', 'Dennis', 'Peter', 'Jess'],
        'language': ['Python', 'C', 'Java', 'Python']}

new_data = []
for row in data:
    new_row = {}
    for item in row:
        new_row[item['name']] = item['name']
    new_data.append(new_row)

print(new_data)
header = new_data[0].keys()
print(header)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, header)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(new_data)
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the dictionary keys are turned into the csv headers and the values turned into the rows.

But when running the code I get a `TypeError: 'string indices must be integers'` in line 21.

Comment: can you use pandas?

Comment: I've never heard of it before, I have to do some research about that

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Please provide the full traceback log so we can access the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The issue here is `for row in data`. This is actually iterating over the keys of your `data` dictionary, and then you're iterating over the characters of the dictionary keys:

```py
In [2]: data = {'name' : ['Dave', 'Dennis', 'Peter', 'Jess'],
   ...:         'language': ['Python', 'C', 'Java', 'Python']}
   ...:
   ...: new_data = []
   ...: for row in data:
   ...:     for item in row:
   ...:         print(item)
   ...:
n
a
m
e
l
a
n
g
u
a
g
e
```

### Approach

What you actually need to do is use `zip` to capture both the name and favorite language of each person at the same time:

```py
In [43]: for row in zip(*data.values()):
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:
('Dave', 'Python')
('Dennis', 'C')
('Peter', 'Java')
('Jess', 'Python')
```

Now, you need to `zip` those tuples with the keys from `data`:

```py
In [44]: header = data.keys()
    ...: for row in zip(*data.values()):
    ...:     print(list(zip(header, row)))
    ...:
[('name', 'Dave'), ('language', 'Python')]
[('name', 'Dennis'), ('language', 'C')]
[('name', 'Peter'), ('language', 'Java')]
[('name', 'Jess'), ('language', 'Python')]
```

### Solution

Now you can pass these tuples to the `dict` constructor to create your `rowdicts` which `csv_writer.writerows` requires:

```py
header = data.keys()
new_data = []
for row in zip(*data.values()):
    new_data.append(dict(zip(header, row)))

with open("output.csv", "w+", newline="") as f_out:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, header)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(new_data)
```

Output in `output.csv`:

```
name,language
Dave,Python
Dennis,C
Peter,Java
Jess,Python
```